# Getting template error. 'T" was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, templates

I am just practicing a bst program using templates. Below is the program.

```
template<class T>
class bstnode
{
    public: 
        T key;
        bstnode *left, *right;
        bstnode()
        {
            left=right=0;
        }
        bstnode(const T& el, bstnode *l=0, bstnode *r=0)
        {
            key=el;
            left=l;
            right=r;
        }
};

template<class T>
class bst
{
    protected:
        bstnode<T>* root;
    public:
        bst()
        {
            root=0;
        }
        void insert(T);
        void display();
        void inorder(bstnode<T> *);
};

void inorder(bstnode <T>* b1)  //ERROR 'T' was not declared in scope
{
    if(b1)
    {
        cout<<b1->key;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
    inorder(b1->right);        
    inorder(b1->left);
}

template<class T>
void bst<T>::display()
{
    //bstnode<T> * b=new bstnode<T>();
    //b=root;
    inorder(root);  
}

template<class T>
void bst<T>::insert(T v)
{
    bstnode<T>* b=new bstnode<T>();
    b->key=v;
    if(root==NULL)
    {
        root=b;
    }
    else
    {
        bstnode<T>* temp=root;
        while((temp->left!=NULL)||(temp->right!=NULL))
        {
            if(temp->key > b->key)
            {
                temp=temp->right;
            }
            else
            {
                temp=temp->left;
            }
        }
        if(temp->key < b->key)
        {
            temp->left=b;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->right=b;
        }   
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    bst<int>b;
    b.insert(10);
    b.insert(5);
    b.insert(2);
    return 0;
}
```

During compiling I am getting error 'T' was not declared in scope for the inorder function.

Please help me in solving this problem.

Comment: Of course: you forgot the `template <typename T>` in front of it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write

```
template <typename T>
void bst<T>::inorder(bstnode <T>* b1)  
{
    if(b1) cout<<b1->key;
    else return;
    inorder(b1->right);        
    inorder(b1->left);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your function inorder is outside the class body, you need to add another template, which is referred to inorder outside the class

```
template<class T>
```